# get the list of files in changesets returned by the Outgoing command with mercurial.net

Tags: .net, mercurial

I am using mercurial.net to add a wrapper around mercurial for an admin tool. If I use the Outgoing method to get back an IEnumerable these elements do not have any path action associated with them so I cannot get the list of files that is to be modified. Is this possible to do some other way with these Changeset objects?

http://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/